# .SaveAs method troubleshoot

Tags: excel, vba, save-as

I am having trouble with the .SaveAs and .Close methods. The code will produce a fileName and a directory, but I am unable to save. I receive a method fail pop-up. I would appreciate any help. Thank you!

```
Sub saveAs()

Dim path As String

Dim inputName As String

Dim inputDate As String

Dim workbookName As String

Dim clientName As String

Dim valueDate As String

Dim productName As String

Dim todayDate As String

Dim formatTodayDate As String

Dim fullPath As String
```

```
'user input
inputName = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("macro").Cells(1, 1)
'user input
inputDate = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("macro").Cells(2, 1)
'directory path

path = "C:\\Users\\" & inputName & "\\Chatham Financial Corp\\John Kjelstrom - Valuation\\Companies\\Sundance Bay\\Income and Growth Fund\\" & inputDate & "\\"

'find client name
clientName = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Net Asset Valuation").Cells(3, 2).Value
'find valuation date
valueDate = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Debt Valuation Model").Cells(4, 2).Value
'valuation in file name
productName = "Valuation"
'todays date
todayDate = Now()
formatTodayDate = Format(todayDate, "d/m/yyyy")

'file name
workbookName = clientName
'full path
fullPath = path & workbookName
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True, Filename:=workbookName
```

Comment: Does the path actually exist? You may need to check to see if it does and created it if not. Have you considered using the [Folder Picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.filedialog)?

Comment: Have you tried using single (rather than double) backslash characters in your `path` variable ? In the absence of "method fail pop up" being clarified you might try launching Excel as the admin user before running the code.